# added event listener but 2 clicks needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added event listeners to some `div`s on `$(document).ready`. However, the very first time, it takes two clicks to fire the event (or at least to get the result.)

I'm adding a click handler and showing or hiding the child nodes as an accordion. Any thoughts?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      headers=document.getElementsByClassName("headerH");
      for(var i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
          var headline=headers[i].firstChild.innerText;
          headers[i].firstChild.innerText="+"+headline;
          headers[i].addEventListener('click', accord, false);
      }
  }); 

function accord(){
    listofnodes=this.children;
    for (var i=1; i<listofnodes.length; i++){
        var headline=listofnodes[0].innerText;
        if (listofnodes[i].style.display=="none"){
            listofnodes[i].style.display="block";
            listofnodes[0].innerText="-"+headline.substring(1);
        }
        else {
             listofnodes[i].style.display="none";
             listofnodes[0].innerText="+"+headline.substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('.headerH').on('click', accord);`? Not sure why you use `getElementsByClassName` when you are using `$(document).ready()` I don't think that's the issue though. You should `console.log` what `listofnodes` is spitting out when the first click happens.

Comment: i used the jQuery document.ready vs window.onload because we have some weird frames site and it did't work with onload, but that isn't what you asked. I'll try console.log

Comment: You may try jQueryUI instead for the [accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height) functionality.

Comment: As you've jQuery loaded on page, use it. **Code:** `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.headerH').on('click', accord).each(function () {
        $(this).children().first().text(function (i, oldText) {
            return '+' + oldText;
        })
    });
});

function accord() {
    $(this).children().toggle().text(function (i, oldText) {
        return (oldText[0] === '+' ? '-' : '+') + oldText.substring(1);
    });
}`

Comment: @Tushar Why is this a comment, instead of an answer?

Comment: @TbWill4321 Feel free to add it in your-_accepted_ answer

Comment: @Tushar There wasn't an accepted answer at the time.  Still, large blocks of code don't generally come in as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the javascript property `style.display` is equal to an empty string the first time through.  The initial display property is not populated from your CSS sheets.

If you flip your `if/else` statement around, you should get it working on the first click:

```
if (listofnodes[i].style.display=="block"){
    listofnodes[i].style.display="none";
    listofnodes[0].innerText="+"+headline.substring(1);
}
else {
    listofnodes[i].style.display="block";
    listofnodes[0].innerText="-"+headline.substring(1);
}
```

Edit: For those who want to see this done in the most proper way:

You can use `Window.getComputedStyle` to pull the default value from your stylesheets.  This takes a bit more code, but works in more cases.

```
var element = listofnodes[i];
var display = element.style.display || getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("display");
if (display=="none"){
    element.style.display="block";
    listofnodes[0].innerText="-"+headline.substring(1);
}
else {
    element.style.display="none";
    listofnodes[0].innerText="+"+headline.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
listofnodes[i].style.display=="none"
```

This is probably returning `false` on the first click. The reason is because the DOM element does not actually have a `display` attribute on it yet. Then when you click, your `else` block adds the attribute. So then your second click will return `true`.

I usually solve this by doing something like this:

```
listofnodes[i].style.display = listofnodes[i].style.display === (undefined || 'block') ? "none" : "block";
```

Comment: thanks I wondered about that. However, is that the case even though I have set the display property in the CSS as none to start with?

Comment: Yes, it's still the case, because JavaScript is looking at the DOM node rather than the CSS stylesheet when it checks the `.style` attribute of an element. CSS styles aren't added to the DOM nodes themselves when the page is rendered. They're just used by the browser to determine how the element should be displayed. So the browser knows that the element should be displayed as 'none', but the element itself doesn't, so to speak.